# Is thru axle with rim brake okay?

Tags: brakes, rim-brake, through-axle

so I have converted my disc brake Road Bike to rim brake. My road bike frame is thru axle but it has a slot for rim brake so i decided to go for rim brake and I removed the rotors from the hub and planning to put a colored bolts for the rotor slot (just for the design). Is this build okay?

[image: Close-up of front brake; it is printed SHIMANO]
[image: Rear triangle showing rear wheel and rear brake]
[image: Close-up of rear brake; it is branded ULTEGRA]

Comment: Could we have some photos please ?   use [edit] to add them.  I'm looking for a brake track on the rim, and proper caliper mounting holes, and that your pads match your rim.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IwBwInl Here are some images of my rim and rim brake. Can you tell if the rim will work fine cause I ordered a new rim just to make sure it suits for rim brake cause my current rim is stock for disc brake. Picture of thru axle and rim brake: https://imgur.com/a/1hYxZTn Thanks!

Comment: Almost all rim brake rims have a machined silver brake track. I can't see that on the rim in the photo you provided. Are you sure you asked for a rim brake rim? NB: when I said almost all rim brake rims, for practical purposes I do mean all of them. Some high end ones (DT Swiss, formerly Boyd) have a black/grey plasma electrolytic oxidation coating, but you would presumably know if you had bought one of these.

Comment: Larger and better-lit photos from multiple angles would be a big help. I can't tell from the front wheel brake photo if the pads will touch only the metal braking rim (good) or also touch the tire (very bad).

Comment: @Weiwen Ng I asked the local shop where I bought this bike, and they said that the rim is fine for rim brake cause they said that its an “alloy” but I honestly doubt it cause the rim has no brake line. But I ordered a new rim, here’s what it looks like https://imgur.com/a/50pvvth (description of product says its for rim brakes)

Comment: @Kent Did you mean to say you ordered a new *wheel*, not just a rim? It will be very expensive to rebuild your old wheel with a new rim.

Comment: @Armand I think I ordered only just a rim cause I will just transfer the spokes and hub into it. 

Comment: If you know how to do it it is fine. It is quite expensive to have someone to do it for you.

Comment: Without meaning offense, I wonder if there is a language barrier here. If the shop actually said that the rim is fine for rim brakes because it's an "alloy", they are mistaken. It needs a brake track. You can make a carbon rim with a rim brake track. For that matter, I bet you could make wood or steel rims with brake tracks, but they probably don't work as well. The rim you linked to that you said you ordered is clearly a rim brake rim. However, you can't simply transfer the spokes, you need to calculate the correct spoke length for the new rim and the old hub.

Comment: @Weiwen Ng I see. Logically thinking, I have 24 holes hub and rim, and I ordered a 24 holes rim as well. Do I still have to adjust the spokes sir? 

Comment: @Kant - spokes are specific lengths to match the geometry of a rim. Unless the new rim has the exact same profile, which unlikely, then you'll need different spokes too.

Comment: Also why are you doing all this in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

It is of course in general OK to but rim brakes on your bike IF the frame supports them and IF the rim has the braking surface. You will need the right brake levers and cables. If your disc brakes were mechanical, they may or may not use the right actuation ratio - depends on the kind of rim brakes (road, V-brakes, cantis,...).

But I do not think we can say more from your brief description.

Thru axles are irrelevant. Or at least they do not interfere with rim brakes in any way.

**Update:** Your old wheel rim does not appear to have the braking surface and is thus incompatible with rim brakes.

**Update2:** The new Cosmics should be OK.

Comment: And from what I've understood from an engineer explaining on YouTube, the holding power on a QR is 10X higher than that of a thru-axle.

Comment: @Carel: it's not really meaningful, as QR are plenty capable of holding the wheels in. The main difference is in the failure mode if the QR or TA is improperly installed, TAs are more tolerant of user error.

Comment: Good job pointing out that disc rims typically don't have brake tracks that rim brakes would grasp on. I had wondered about this myself.

Comment: Thank you for helping sir and the other guys as well ☺️